# use url containes cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, post

in terinal i am getting output of a post method using following code:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8787/rpc/getSingleSecurity' -d @data -H 'Cookie: user-id=algotree|Mon%C%2013%20Mar%2023%2009%3A48%3A16%20GMT|EVtpHw4dlEYCnrIxUQZORgJXvGk%3D'
```

The data i have is as follows:

```
{"method":"getSingleSecurity", "params":[{"ticker":"AAPL"} ], "clientId": "31d0c653-d7e5-44b6-98b5-8c084f99514a", "version":1354777632}
```

The output is as follows:

```
{"ep":"false","result":{"CUSIP":["037833100"],"name":["Apple Inc"],"ticker":["AAPL"]}}
```

I want to use the output in javascript. How can i use the output of this url using $.ajax() method?

Comment: is the helful to you ??

Comment: please check the edit in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code snippet below, using ajax for post request. You can also use it for authenticated requests by using cookie as described below.

```
var cookie = $.cookie('yourCookieNameHere');
var reqUrl = requestUrl;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: reqUrl, 
    dataType: "json", 
    data: {
        utf8: true, 
        _method:"POST",
        "method":"getSingleSecurity", 
        "params":[{"ticker":"AAPL"} ], 
        "clientId": "31d0c653-d7e5-44b6-98b5-8c084f99514a", 
        "version":1354777632             //replace these with variables if any
    }, 
    Cookie: cookie
}).success(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // you can use response data from response
    console.log("This is response data " + response);
});
```